# Get handles to all windows of a process

Tags: c#

In C# using the process class I can get the handle to the Main Window of a process but I need access to a window that is not the main window of its process. How can I get the handle to all of the windows of a process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx) function might help you out. The child windows could also have children and so on.

There is also [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx) and [EnumThreadWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

P/Invoking the [`EnumThreadWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495%28VS.85%29.aspx) function of user32, the callback you provide would be given the handles of the windows for a given thread.  `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` should return to you all the relevant threads with which to call `EnumThreadWindows`.

Answer (score 3):

You can P/Invoke `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the thread ID for the UI thread that owns the main window.  From there, you can find any other top-level window owned by that thread with `EnumThreadWindows()`.  Any child windows (controls) owned by a top-level window can be found with `EnumChildWindows()`.  Visit [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) for the necessary P/Invoke declarations.