# How to enumerate all windows within a process?

Tags: c#, windows, process

I need to capture particular windows of 3rd party process. I can find main window handle as Process.MainWindowHandle, but what I can use to list other windows?

I am using C# / .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3rd party aplication launched other windows not as child windows.

It is possible to find out what is structure using Spy++ tool which comes with Visual Studio.

After this, I was able to find necessary window using FindWindowEx function using WindowClassName (taken from Spy++):
lastWindows = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, lastWindows, m.WindowClassName, null);

Answer (score 3):

[.NET (C#): Getting child windows when you only have a process handle or PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111/net-c-getting-child-windows-when-you-only-have-a-process-handle-or-pid)

Answer (score 3):

The [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx) function might help you out. The child windows could also have children and so on.

There is also [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx) and [EnumThreadWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495(VS.85).aspx)

Another post here with some more details: [Get handles to all windows of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238609/c-get-handles-to-all-windows-of-a-process)

Comment: Thanks for this name - I will close question when problem will be solved

Answer (score 3):

Use the Win32 API [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) (and if you want [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx))

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumThreadWindowsCallback callback, IntPtr extraData);
```

Then check which process each window belongs to by using the Win32 API [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HandleRef handle, out int processId);
```