# In C# how do you Show a Hidden window?

Tags: c#, window

I tried to set the WindowState of the System.Diagnostics.Process object but that didn't work. Neither did the WinAPI ShowWindow function because it requires a handle to a Window which I cannot acquire because the window that I want to show is hidden (Meaning that its MainWindowHandle defaults to Zero when I call MainWindowHandle on the Process object.)

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the type of the window you're trying to show?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because MainWindowHandle is zero, it does not necessarily mean you cannot get a handle to the window. By convention, the MainWindowHandle is the first window the application creates, but it can be a bit hit and miss. Having it return zero is not unusual.

You should use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find the windows owned by a process.