# Embed Teamviewer in Win Forms Applications

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child, parent

(C#) hi want to incorporate in my win forms Teamviewer.

how could this be done?

The following code works with other app like notepad or paint ... but with TeamViewer not working.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    { 
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
                SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
            }
        }
    }
```

stay blessed!

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you might be trying with just exe name as `Teamviewer.exe`.

**Solution :** You should provide the complete path of the Teamviewer software where it is installed/located exactly in your pc.

**Why :** `notepad.exe` works without complete path as it hasbeen registerd in Environmental Variables so it will be know even there is no complete path.

if you want to run the `Teamviewer.exe` without complete path you can the set the complete path in `Environment Variables`.

but you can just provide the Complete Path to open it.

Note : Change the below path asper your installation path.

Try This:

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\TeamViewer.exe");
```

Comment: Yes i got de full path. the problem is that it open the teamviewer but not open in my win form.

Answer (score 1):

Team viewer is not an Microsoft Product.

All application can't be inherited and make use of its instance in your windows application. usually the windows standard applications like `MS office, Note Pad, System Registries,` config files.

You can execute the application but to inherit you need following things

- Assembly Reference ( **.dll** files)
- Name space for **override / create object** of such type.
- **Documentation** for writing code.

If you has all these things you can create its instance / integrate the items in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer launches multiple windows. The MainWindowHandle you are referring to, is probably not the right one.

You could try to enumerate all windows owned by the Teamviewer process/thread and then set the parent for one of these. For more information, take a look at this question: [How to enumerate all windows belonging to a particular process using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net)