# Get title of a hidden windows

Tags: c#

I can get title of a windows that it appear on the taskbar using following code

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("processNameHere"))
{
   string title = p.MainWindowTitle;
}
```

But if windows not appear on the takbask, string title will be empty.

So I want to ask how can I get title of a windows that is does not appear on the taskbar?

Comment: Possibly help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, I use my own `Window` class that handles this plus some extras.

See:

```
public class Window
{
    public IntPtr Handle;
    public string Title;
    public int ProcessId;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return IsWindowVisible(Handle);
        }
    }
    public FormWindowState WindowState
    {
        get
        {
            WindowPlacement winp = new WindowPlacement();
            winp.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(winp);
            GetWindowPlacement(Handle, ref winp);
            return (FormWindowState)(winp.ShowCmd - 1);
        }
        set
        {
            ShowWindowAsync(Handle, (int)value + 1);
        }
    }

    public Window(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        PostMessage(Handle, 0x10, 0, 0);
    }
    public void SetTitle(string title)
    {
        SetWindowText(Handle, title);
    }

    public static Window[] GetAllWindows()
    {
        List<Window> list = new List<Window>();
        EnumWindows(delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(256);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, title, 256);
                Window window = new Window(hWnd);
                window.Title = title.ToString();
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out window.ProcessId);
                lock (list) list.Add(window);
            }
            catch { }
            return true;
        }, 0);
        return list.ToArray();
    }

    private struct Rect
    {
        int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
    }
    private struct Point
    {
        int X, Y;
    }
    private struct WindowPlacement
    {
        public int Length, Flags, ShowCmd;
        public Point ptMinPosition, ptMaxPosition;
        public Rect rcNormalPosition;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string strNewWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc ewp, int lParam);
    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WindowPlacement lpwndpl);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    private static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
}
```