# How to run visible and close process when button click

Tags: c#, exe, kill, visible

I call another form exe file into my main form but i did not want to show up it need to be visible. then i need to close the exe file when clicking the button .

i call my another form exe use of the code

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\server.exe";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

please help me how it run visible?

the when i need to close that exe i use

```
Process.Kill();
```

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Process.Kill()'

I get this error.

help me how to open another exe as visible? and how to close it when button click?

Comment: If you call Process.Start, the exe will be started and if that exe has a window, the window will be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question:

`Kill()` is an **instance** method of `Process`, but you try to call it like a *static* method.

You need to use the `Process` instance returned by `Process.Start()` and call `Kill()` on that instance:

```
Process myProcessInstance = Process.Start(startInfo);
//...
myProcessInstance.Kill();
```

---

For your *first* question: I don't fully understand your problem? Do you *want* the window to appear or not? Should it be visible or *in*visible? And what is happening (do you see it or not) when you run your current code?

You may have a look at [`ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) properties.

If you don't want to see the form created by the *.exe you started you unfortunatly cannot trigger that simply via the `ProcessStartInfo`. You will have to use the Windows API to enumerate the windows of the started process and access these windows through that API. [Here is a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531840/5528593).

If the `server.exe` is created by you, you may think about giving it some command line arguments to tell it not to show the forms.

Comment: My 1st Question is that : i don't want to show my exe file. i want to make my exe as visible = false;

Comment: @Divi updated the answer, but it's not a simple thing to do.

Comment: Thank you Friend for your help... I make my form as hidden with help of Opacity = 0%.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store you Process in a variable:

```
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

process.Kill();
```