# closing IE popups from C# application

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, popupwindow

I made a C# application for closing popups of various programs. I use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses() then I inspect MainWindowTitle of each process hunting popups which are on my black list. Nothing fancy. It works fine except for IE popups like: "close all tabs?", "would you like to use default security settings?", "would you like to make IE your default browser?", etc. As I see, IE popups do not appear in the list. How can I find and close them?

Comment: **Main**WindowTitle, what is there are [many windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2531828/1997232) opened by same process?

Comment: No, as I said: popups of various programs