# How I can get a find dialog of web browser control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the find dialog (Which opens with a control + F) as an object, for to know if it's active.

How I do it?

I went through all the parameters of the web browser control and found nothing.

Comment: I've never found a way to pop it up, but, if I remember correctly, `<Ctrl>+F` works.  I shipped a quickie internal app with instructions that said "if you want to find something on the page, use  `<Ctrl>+F`.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive ?

Comment: I want to hide the window when I walk out of the main window or out of this window, and when he goes to the find it seems to get out of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the WebBrowser control, nor the native IWebBrowser2 interface expose the find dialog. The only interaction is launching the dialog by calling an OLE command:

```
SHDocVw.WebBrowser webBrowserInstance = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
webBrowserInstance.ExecWB(
                    SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_FIND,
                    SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT,
                    null, null);
```

This works well, but neither can you pass any variables, nor do you get any back. The find dialog unfortunately isn't a child window, and it doesn't have any identifying classes or attributes. Basically you'd need to inspect all top-level windows belonging to your process, and find out if one of them is the dialog in question. Then you can send a WM_CLOSE to the window, or call CloseWindow, or somemthing similar.

There is a good collection of functions to search for (top-level) windows belonging to a process here:
[How to enumerate all windows belonging to a particular process using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net)